# Qt, Pimpl, ошибка: определение dllimport статические данные-член не разрешено

Tags: c++, qt, dllimport, pimpl

Получаю ошибку компиляции: ...\moc_client.cpp:65: ошибка: C2491: Client::staticMetaObject: определение dllimport статические данные-член не разрешено

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, в чем проблема.

**.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = api

CONFIG += c++11

QT += core
CONFIG += console

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
    client.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    client.h \
    client_p.h \
    test_global.h
```

**client.h:**

```
#ifndef TEST_CLIENT_H
#define TEST_CLIENT_H

#include "test_global.h"
#include <QScopedPointer>
#include <QObject>

class ClientPrivate;

class TEST_SHARED_EXPORT Client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Client)
public:
    explicit Client(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual ~Client();
protected:
    QScopedPointer<ClientPrivate> d_ptr;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Client*)

#endif // TEST_CLIENT_H
```

**client_p.h:**

```
#ifndef CLIENT_P_H
#define CLIENT_P_H

#include "client.h"
#include <QPointer>

class ClientPrivate
{
    Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC(Client)
public:
    ClientPrivate(Client *q) : q_ptr(q)
    {
    }
    Client *q_ptr;
};

#endif // CLIENT_P_H
```

**test_global.h:**

```
#ifndef API_GLOBAL_H
#define API_GLOBAL_H

#include <QObject>

#if defined(TEST_LIBRARY)
#  define TEST_SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define TEST_SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // API_GLOBAL_H
```

**client.cpp:**

```
#include "client_p.h"

Client::Client(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    d_ptr(new ClientPrivate(this))
{
}

Client::~Client()
{
}

#include "moc_client.cpp"
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать пробел в `# define`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При построении DLL под Windows все public функции и классы должны быть отмечены как экспортные: `__declspec(dllexport)`. Когда компилируется код, который использует библиотеку, те же функции и классы должны быть отмечены как импортные: `__declspec(dllimport)`.

Обычно для этого в проекте библиотеки определяют препроцессорный символ. Клиент библиотеки компилируется без этого символа.

```
#ifndef API_GLOBAL_H
#define API_GLOBAL_H

#include <QObject>

#if defined(TEST_LIBRARY)        // library is compiled, public library functions are exported
#  define TEST_SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else                            // client is compiled, public library functions are imported
#  define TEST_SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT  
#endif

#endif // API_GLOBAL_H
```

Итак, когда вы компилируете библиотеку, добавьте препроцессорный символ `TEST_LIBRARY`. Когда вы компилируете код, который эту библиотеку использует, `TEST_LIBRARY` не должен быть определен.

Comment: Вы правы, только добавьте в ответ, что ему надо дописать `DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS TEST_LIBRARY`